# Theano tensor types: Python

Tags: python-3.x, theano

CODE:

```
x=T.dscalar('x')
y=T.dscalar('y')
z=T.dscalar('z')
z=x+y
f= function([x,y],z)
```

UPON RUNNING:

$ T.dscalar

TensorType(float64, scalar)

$ x.type

TensorType(float64, scalar)

$ z.type

TensorType(float64, scalar)

$ x.type is T.dscalar

True   <<<<<<<-------------------------------(1)

$ z.type is T.dscalar

False  <<<<<<<-------------------------------(2)

Why isn't (1) & (2) same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line `z = T.dscalar('z')` is pointless because it's not a graph input. It's gets discarded when you do `z=x+y`. The type object for `z` is constructed in `make_node` method of an Op, instead of just using `T.dscalar`.

Finally, Python `is` operator compares whether two object is *identical* rather than *equal*. If you check `z.type == T.dscalar` it will be `True`.